# Calling a method from another class with the getMethod gives an error

Tags: java, reflection, hashset

So, as the title describes, I am in need of help with calling a method from a class to another. So, to explain a bit further: I'm storing classes in a `HashSet`. Now I'm trying to access a method located in that class chosen in that `HashSet`, but it rather gives me that error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source).

Code:

```
 Class<Task> neededClass = taskHandler.getTaskClass("NodeMovementTask");
                try {
                    neededClass.getMethod("addToQueue", Timeline.class, int.class).invoke(timeline, cycleCount);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                        | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                        | SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Thats the getTaskClass method

```
public Class<Task> getTaskClass(String classToSearch) {
    Class<Task> returningClass = null;
    for(Class<Task> foundClass : tasks) {
        if(foundClass.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("packages." + classToSearch)) {
            System.out.println("Found!");
            return returningClass = foundClass;
        }
    }
    return returningClass;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `invoke` method is the object instance you want to invoke the method on. If the method is static you can simply supply `null` as that first argument. Otherwise you need to supply the instance that you actually want to call the method on:

```
neededClass.getMethod("addToQueue", Timeline.class, int.class)
     .invoke(instance, timeline, cycleCount);
             ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I got the concept. But somehow it's also weird. The instance needed is neededClass, so, in order of instance I'd put neededClass in there? `neededClass.getMethod("addToQueue", Timeline.class, int.class).invoke(neededClass, timeline, cycleCount);`. God I'm confused. Just did that, this is what I get for both using `neededClass` and `neededClass.getClass()` `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` @K-Erlandsson

Comment: @Sh0ck You can not put `neededClass` there - that is a `Class` object. You need to put an instance of `neededClass` there. If you do not already have such an instance you can create it reflectively as well by calling `neededClass.newInstance()` (assuming there is a no-argument constructor, otherwise you'll have to get the constructor and call that).